# Working with a (huge) tree structure, what would be a better choice: SSR or CSR?

Tags: rendering, server-side-rendering, client-side-rendering

I like to build an app which deals with a tree structure. To get the tree, I need to gather the relationship between nodes to build it up.

I was using *React-Redux* (CSR) to get data from the DB and build up the tree in the *store*. Now, it seems that *Next.js* is better, but it’s a SSR, I’m wondering how the tree structure could be built: each time I’m using it or the structure could be built once (and be updated if needed and we could use it as long as we want to)?

The question could be considered as stupid: I’ve never been a professional programmer, but I like to build apps for myself.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Sounds about right. Your tree structure shouldn't need updating until the DB is mutated.  You could start updating your cached server-side rendering data on every mutation, or do it in intervals. It depends on what the user requirements are. For example, you could use client-side rendering to give the user a faux representation of the tree - which has not actually been updated server-side, or you could make them wait for the server to update its cache, and update the client's view of the render only thereafter.